# Two canvas overlopping each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i designed a web component that get's displayed on a canvas, name flx-chart

I'm using this code to try to display 2 of my web components, it should be one after each other and without overlapping:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Easy Pie</div>
                <flx-chart type='bar' width='200' height='200'></flx-chart>
                <flx-chart type='polarArea' width='407' height='162'></flx-chart>

            </div>
```

i used this format to my other web components and they worked, i thought this is a problem with canvas as the other didn't used it, i'm new on this and i haven't found anything about posicionating canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wasn't setting different id's for each canvas, i added a new parameter to the call, id="sample" and each canvas has his own different one